# Find greater number from map inside map in java

Tags: java

```
HashMap<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> outer = new HashMap<>();
String abc = //someString;
maxNumber = //somevalue;
minNumber = //somevalue;
Map<Integer,Integer> inner = new HashMap<>();
inner.put(minNumber, maxNumber);
outer.put(abc, inner);
```

There is code something like below. I am retrieving greater number from inner map, tried but can't get.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> outer1 : outer.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Feature: " + outer1.getKey() +  "\n");
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : outer1.getValue().entrySet()) {
   //.... stuck here.
}
```

How can I get greater value from inner map?

Comment: Can you please tell us what does it mean when you say "can't get". Do you get `null` or error?

Comment: Could you include an explanation of why you need to do this?

Comment: It means i have tried. @SteveFest

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes.
there is key in outer map and two values in inner map. From inner map i want to extract greater value. because if i got greater value then i want to use 'key' for further operation.

Comment: @NamrataNShahade In your text you state '...and two values in inner map'. But according to your code (`inner.put(minNumber, maxNumber);`) you have an inner map with exactly one key/value pair. Might this be the fault?

Comment: @blafasel i have written rough code. this is not exact. It is assumption that we have more values.

Comment: When say you want "greater value" from inner map, what must this "greater" value be greater than?

Answer (score 0):

`minNumber` is the key to the inner Map. So the value is `maxNumber`.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> outer1 : outer.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Feature: " + outer1.getKey() +  "\n");
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : outer1.getValue().entrySet()) {
        Integer key = entry.getKey(); // == minNumber
        Integer value = entry.getValue(); // == maxNumber
}
```